# Fraction Calculator app

Tags: java, class, calculator, fractions

```
public class Calculator 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String choice = "";
        String userFract = "0";
        String userFract2 = "0";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fract = "0";
        int clearCounter = 0;

        String add = "a"; String multiply = "m";
        String subtract = "s"; String divide = "d";
        String reciprocal = "r"; String clear = "c";
        String reverse = "n"; String proper = "p";
        String improper = "i"; String quit = "q";



        while(!choice.equals("q"))
        {
            if(clearCounter == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter a fraction: ");
                userFract = scan.nextLine();

               clearCounter++;
            }

            NewFraction currentFract = NewFraction.parseNewFraction(userFract);
            fract = currentFract.toString();
            System.out.println(fract);

            System.out.println("add:         a,  clear:            c");
            System.out.println("subtract:    s,  reverse sign:     n");
            System.out.println("multiply:    m,  proper display:   p");
            System.out.println("divide:      d,  improper display: i");
            System.out.println("reciprocal:  r,  quit:             q");
            System.out.print("-->");
            choice = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");

            if(choice.equals(add))
            {
                System.out.print("Enter another fraction: ");
                userFract2 = scan.nextLine();
                NewFraction newFract = NewFraction.parseNewFraction(userFract2);

               NewFraction Fract = currentFract.Add(newFract);
               System.out.println(Fract.Proper());
            }

            if(choice.equals(clear))
            {
                clearCounter--;
            }

          }


    }
}
```

I am working on a program for a fraction calculator, and like my NewFraction file works properly but I am having trouble wit the calculator file.so my file compiles and executes but the output is weird. It displaces the right answer and on the next line, it also displays the original fraction? Idk what to do.. HELP!

Comment: Please be explicit which statement is printing what. From the problem statement, it is not clear. A suggestion. Instead of nextLine, use either nextInt or nextFloat.

Comment: No, @vijar, `nextLine` is correct.  She's parsing the line inside the `parseNewFraction` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this line

```
System.out.println(Fract.Proper());
```

with

```
currentFract = Fract;
```

The fraction `Fract` will be printed out at the start of the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: I tried what you said and it still does the same thing again?!?!

Comment: So you now have one less `System.out.println` than you did before, but you're still getting just as many lines printed to the console?

Comment: no that was not the problem.. I fixed it! Thanks for the help!